# How to obtain validator info with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In mongo shell I can retrieve the validator info of one collection with

```
db.getCollectionInfos({name: 'collection'})[0].options.validator
```

How is it done with pymongo?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit obscure but it can be done:

```
import pymongo
db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']

x = db.command({'listCollections': 1, 'filter': {'name': 'testcollection'}})
print(x.get('cursor').get('firstBatch')[0].get('options').get('validator'))
```